# Cutting rectangle not using Rectangle :)

Tags: c#, bitmap

If I have 4 points at bitmap (left top corner, right top corner, left bottom corner, right bottom corner) how to cut bitmap not using Rectangle method to cut rectangle of that points? And save it as .png?

Comment: Why don't you want to use Rectangle?

Comment: I nead to cut part of image and it can be placed different ways on different angle. @edit: it must to be very accurate.

Comment: Maybe he means polygon (with 4 points) which isn't necessarily a rectangle?

Comment: A PNG image will be rectangular. How do you want to place your polygon-clipped image in the resulting rectangle?

Comment: I don't understand the _"And save it as .png"_ I never saved a polygon.

Comment: so, how to save that image after cuting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have 4 points: `p1, p2, p3, p4`. You can draw your image so that only the part of image in the region of the polygon made by those 4 points using the `Clip` property of the `Graphics` object. Here is the test which draws an image on a form:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
  gp.AddPolygon(new []{Point.Empty, new Point(100,10), new Point(200,300), new Point(30,200) });//add p1,p2,p3,p4 to the Polygon
  e.Graphics.Clip = new Region(gp);
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(yourImage, Point.Empty);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can crop images (save partial images) like this:

```
int newWidth = x2-x1;
int newHeight = y2-y1;

Bitmap smallBitmap = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
bigImage.DrawImage(0, 0, smallBitmap, x1, y1, newWidth, newHeight);

smallBitmap.Save(....);
```

Comment: "Cannot resolve symbol "DravImage""? but i have using System.Drawing;

Comment: DrawImage you are looking for.  Notice the 'w', found here: _Bitmap.DrawImage Method_ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee433188.aspx